# how to get the integer value from javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function

```
function answerQ(value) {
var newVal = value;
alert(newVal);
}
```

and the input button

```
<input type="button" onClick="answerQ(this.value)" value="Answer Q2">
```

how can I get just the integer "2" out of this??

Comment: Please show us your attempt so far and explain what didn't work.

Comment: You should redesign your application. At the very least, you could add a data-attribute with the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove anything that isn't a number

```
function answerQ(value) {
    var newVal = +value.replace(/\D/g,'');
    alert(newVal);
}
```

Comment: `+value.slice(-1)` ;)